# New to Ionic: Typescript Error in App.Component.Ts

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I am getting a TypeScript Error in my Ionic app. I have a sidemenu app, and was separating the menu into it's own component so that I could add a login page more easily. I have been following this guide to do so: http://roblouie.com/article/344/ionic-2-hide-menu-or-tabs-for-login-screen/

In my new app.component.ts I have the following code:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Nav, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import { MenuComponent } from "./menu.component";

@Component({
  template: '<ion-nav #baseNav></ion-nav>'
})
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild('baseNav') nav: Nav;

  constructor(public platform: Platform, public statusBar: StatusBar, public splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    this.initializeApp();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.nav.push(MenuComponent, { animate: false });
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
      SplashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
}
```

I am fairly new with Ionic and I have been mostly following guides to get started. Any advice on the matter would be greatly appreciated. Here is the error message I am getting:

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SV36.png)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the instances that Angular injects in the constructor (`DI`) instead of the static methods of the `StatusBar` and the `SplashScreen` classes, as shown below:

```
initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.statusBar.styleDefault();
        this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
}
```